# Cannot access HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise

Tags: c#, registry

I'd appreciate if someone can help me out with the issue I am stack on.

I wrote a simple program in C# to check  if the following key exists 
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\UpgradeCodes\product_upgrade_GUID

It returns true on all Windows (if the key exists) except on Windows Server Enterprise 2008 x64 SP2 where it returns System.NullReferenceException although the key exists. 
Actually I get NullReferenceException if I try to access any key inside the \Installer registry. It looks like this Installer key is somehow protected. 
Same thing happens when trying to access "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Installer\UpgradeCodes" key.

The following code should return "HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer" but it returns NullReferenceException:

```
RegistryKey rk = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"Installer");
return rk.ToString();
```

Does anyone know any limitations for accessing the Installer Windows registry? (UAC is disabled and user is admin)

Thank you

Comment: CAn you access the key in regedit running as administrator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are running a 32 bit process on a 64 bit system and the [registry redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232.aspx) is taking you to the 32 bit view of the registry. Where those keys do not exist.

Your options include:

- Open a 64 bit view of the registry using the [`RegistryView`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registryview.aspx) enumeration. Note that this requires .net 4. For older versions of .net you would need to use p/invoke to read the 64 bit view of the registry from a 32 bit process.
- Switch to a 64 bit process.

Comment: Hi,
I am forced to use .net 3.5 but I don't think the problem is the registry redirection. 
I already checked, I am able to access any registry other than the Installer. 

For example if I create key HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer11\
I am able to access it.

Comment: Yes it is 32bit. I can make it 64bit because then it won't run on 32bit OS.

Comment: This is still the answer. The redirector takes you to HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node etc. One option is AnyCPU target. But how you solve the problem is tangential. My answer explains the behaviour you see.

Comment: Hi David,
I did some more test and indeed you were right. The redirection is the problem. 
My confusion came from the fact that I was able to access key that I manually created HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer1, but I didn't noticed that Windows automatically created the same key under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\WOW6432Node\ ... so I was actually redirected. 

Thank you for your help.