# NullReferenceException when trying to read a registry key with C#

Tags: c#, registry

I'm trying to read and write to the same registry key. However I can't seem to access it. I've checked the path a million times and it's correct.

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\apart\\Shell\\Open\\Command");
MessageBox.Show(key.ToString());
```

Comment: Please also see if [Cannot access HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer on Windows Server 2008 Enterprise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9180563/cannot-access-hkey-classes-root-installer-on-windows-server-2008-enterprise) helps solve your issue (FYI all I did was Google `C# OpenSubKey returns null`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`LocalMachine` corresponds to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`.

`ClassesRoot` represents `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

Try

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("apart\\Shell\\Open\\Command");
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the following:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey("apart\\Shell\\Open\\Command");
MessageBox.Show(key.ToString());
```

Note the [ClassesRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.classesroot(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [LocalMachine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.localmachine(v=vs.110).aspx).